# React Redux problem : SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working on a react appliction and I have a page that make a multiple GET http calls and store data in my redux.
The problem is after 10 or 15calls the navigator crash and I get an error :
[image]

What is the limit for storing data in my React app ? And how to solve this error ? :

```
application state or actions payloads are too large making Redux DevTools serialization slow and consuming a lot of memory
```

Comment: Copied from https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/error-code-sbox-fatal-memory-exceeded/m-p/1488651: "SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED means that the tab used more memory than permitted for the sandboxed process. Edge currently sets the same limits as Chrome; the limits are so high (4gb-16gb) that exceeding them is almost always an indication of a memory leak or JavaScript error on the part of the site"

Comment: Thanks @timotgl, but all my downloaded data from api is less than 40MB, how can I solve it ?

Comment: Maybe check if this is huge amount of data is really global state that you need in many components. It can be a solution to store the data somewhere else (in memory at runtime) and only put references to individual items in redux.